# Empty list of Keys refreshed [] on Spring Cloud Config Server (Spring Boot application)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

In my Spring Cloud config server pom.xml I have

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-bus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In bootstrap.properties I have specified with spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri the repository to fetch configuration properties from (as yml files). I have set up a Github webhook and have ngrok forwarding POST requests to port 8888 that the config server is listening on. When I commit a change to a yml configuration file, everything seems to go as expected:

1. In ngrok console window there is a POST request to /monitor and response with 200.
2. The delivery is marked successful on Github's webhook management page.
3. The following log entries are created in config server's console window.

   ```
   2018-03-14 13:55:03.023  INFO 17004 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] o.s.c.c.monitor.PropertyPathEndpoint     : Refresh for: develop_localhost
   2018-03-14 13:55:04.451  INFO 17004 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
   2018-03-14 13:55:04.483  INFO 17004 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@d3f5ec1: startup date [Wed Mar 14 13:55:04 EET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
   2018-03-14 13:55:04.521  INFO 17004 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a4e4f18] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
   2018-03-14 13:55:06.027  INFO 17004 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
   2018-03-14 13:55:06.041  INFO 17004 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
   2018-03-14 13:55:06.043  INFO 17004 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@429eafc3: startup date [Wed Mar 14 13:55:06 EET 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@d3f5ec1
   2018-03-14 13:55:06.053  INFO 17004 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 3.024 seconds (JVM running for 97.323)
   2018-03-14 13:55:06.054  INFO 17004 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@429eafc3: startup date [Wed Mar 14 13:55:06 EET 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@d3f5ec1
   2018-03-14 13:55:06.055  INFO 17004 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@d3f5ec1: startup date [Wed Mar 14 13:55:04 EET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
   2018-03-14 13:55:06.128  INFO 17004 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] o.s.cloud.bus.event.RefreshListener      : Received remote refresh request. Keys refreshed []
   ```

Why is the list of keys refreshed empty? When I check the local property source yml file, the change committed on Github and POSTed to the monitor endpoint is not reflected there either. I am running RabbitMQ on another server in my local network, and I can see on its web management console the connection from the config server and the channel created for it. Yet there are no messages on the overview tab.

This used to work with Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Dalston.SR5 on the occasions when the embedded Tomcat/Jetty managed to start. The main reason to try version upgrades was that the servlet container actually started only like in 10% percent of the launches. Now with Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Finchley.M8, Tomcat always starts but the configuration changes do not seem to propagate to the config server and definitely not to RabbitMQ.

Any ideas?

**Edit June 5th, 2018.**
Now that I have updated spring-boot-starter-parent to 2.0.2.RELEASE in the config server pom.xml, config client gets its configuration from it. But as before, no push notification is propagated to RabbitMQ. Both the config server and client have their respective connections, channels and queues with RabbitMQ.

Now if I change spring-cloud.version to Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT or Finchley.RC2 (and keep Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE or change it to 2.0.1.RELEASE, no difference), I can see a queued message from the config server on the RabbitMQ web management console when it receives a push notification. Fine. The downside of the combination is that when config client tries to fetch its settings from the server, the server logs the exception below

```
2018-06-04 16:16:12.352 ERROR 10428 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load environment] with root cause

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.HttpClientConfigurableHttpConnectionFactory.lookupHttpClientBuilder(HttpClientConfigurableHttpConnectionFactory.java:69) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
```

and because the client does not get its configuration, it fails to boot.

What would be the working combination of Spring Boot and Cloud versions to have both full RabbitMQ integration (with messages propagated to RabbitMQ) and successful config server and client interaction? Like I mentioned earlier, this used to work with Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Dalston.SR5, but downgrading to them is not an option.

Comment: There is a bug in boot 2.0.0.RELEASE that may be causing this.

Comment: Is there something I could do to have this possible bug documented and later fixed?

Comment: Wait for spring boot 2.0.1

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Can you give us updates about the problem?